# Docker volume is not reflecting changes

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am just learing docker and practising using simple project.

code:

```js
const express= require("express");
const app=express();

const PORT=3000;

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    return res.send("welcome to first tutorial");
})

app.listen(PORT,function(){
    console.log("successfully connected...");
})
```

I containerised it and ran using command:-

`docker run --rm -it -v %cd%/abc/ -p 3000:3000 --name docker-container-1 docker-image-1`

My Dockerfile looks like:-

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /abc

COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

so when I made changes in `res.send("...")` then it should reflect that changes but it is not reflecting changes.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks In Advance..!!!